# XML parsing with smart tag grouping in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing

Here's an example of the conversion I'm trying to achieve.
Source XML:

```
<cats>
  <cat>John</cat>
  <cat>Peter</cat>
</cats>
```

Result:

```
{'cats' => ['John', 'Peter']}
```

And I would like the value of `'cats'` in resulting hash to be an array even if there's only a single `<cat>` in source XML.

So, I would like the parser to apply the rule:

> If node `xyzs` contains one or more child nodes with names `xyz` (and
>   no other nodes), then node `xyzs` should be represented as an array in resulting hash, with name `xyzs` (and each element of the array should be the content of a corresponding `xyz` element).

Here's how it can be achieved using [XmlSimple](http://xml-simple.rubyforge.org/) lib:

```
XmlSimple.xml_in('cats.xml',{:forcearray=>['cat'], :grouptags=>{"cats"=>"cat"}})
```

However, I have to put in all the names of target elements, and it seems there are no other way to define the forcearray/grouptags behavior within XmlSimple.

It wouldn't be hard to hack a pre-processing routine which would extract all the names and then pass them into xml_in method, but there's probably more elegant (i.e., already written) way to do this?

(I'd be happy to use any other XML parsing lib if it capable of the transformation)

---

**UPD**: If it's matter, my end target is to save the resulting hash into MongoDB (i.e. overall conversion is XML -> BSON)

---

**UPD2**: Again, I **DO NOT** want to specify the names of the elements which should be treated as arrays, I'd like the lib to do the magic for me.

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment.

Comment: There are not too many assignments which starts with "Find a lib which.."

Answer (score 1):

Using Nokogiri, we can write this code:

```
require 'inflector'
require 'nokogiri'

def get_xml_stuff(xml, singular)
  plural = Inflector.pluralize(singular)
  return_hash = {plural => []}
  xml.xpath("*/#{plural}/#{singular}").each { |tag| return_hash[plural] << tag.text}
  return return_hash
end
```

This solves the simple case that matches your XmlSimple code, according to my tests. For your further requirement of:

> If node `xyzs` contains one or more child nodes with names `xyz` (and no other nodes), then node `xyzs` should be represented as an array in resulting hash, with name `xyzs` (and each element of the array should be the content of a corresponding `xyz` element).

```
def get_xml_stuff(xml, singular)
  plural = Inflector.pluralize(singular)
  return_hash = {plural => []}
  path = xml.xpath("*/#{plural}/#{singular}")
  path.each { |tag| return_hash[plural] << tag.text} unless path.size != xml.xpath("*/#{plural}/*").children.size
  return return_hash
end
```

That's still not perfect, though, if the same plural appears more than once in the file.

---

Answering **UPD2**. My new version of the function is as follows:

```
def get_xml_stuff(xml, plural)
  singular = Inflector.singularize(plural)
  return_hash = {plural => []}
  path = xml.xpath("./#{singular}")
  path.each { |tag| return_hash[plural] << tag.text} unless path.size != xml.xpath("./*").size
  return return_hash
end
```

Here we start from the plural parent node, and collect all the singular children nodes if all the named children are of that singular name. My new test code becomes:

```
sample_xml = Nokogiri::XML(sample_xml_text)
sample_xml.children.xpath("*").each do |child|
  array = get_xml_stuff(child, child.name)
  p array
end
```

If there is no tag like my example `<pets>`, the following should work:

```
sample_xml = Nokogiri::XML(sample_xml_text)
array = get_xml_stuff(sample_xml.children.first, sample_xml.children.first.name)
p array
```

End **UPD2**

---

For reference, my test was:

```
sample_xml_text = <<-sample
<pets>
  <cats>
    <cat>John</cat>
    <cat>Peter</cat>
  </cats>
  <kitties>
    <kitty>Tibbles</kitty>
    <kitty>Meow-chan</kitty>
    <kitty>Puss</kitty>
  </kitties>
  <giraffes>
    <giraffe>Long Neck</giraffe>
  </giraffes>
  <dogs>
    <dog>Rover</dog>
    <dog>Spot</dog>
    <cat>Peter</cat>
  </dogs>
</pets>
sample

sample_xml = Nokogiri::XML(sample_xml_text)
array = get_xml_stuff(sample_xml, "cat")
p array
array = get_xml_stuff(sample_xml, "kitty")
p array
array = get_xml_stuff(sample_xml, "giraffe")
p array
array = get_xml_stuff(sample_xml, "dog")
p array
```

Comment: see UPD2, please. I don't want to specify the element names.

Answer (score 1):

First find element names that end in an `s`:

```
names = doc.search('*[name()$="s"]').map(&:name).uniq
#=> ["cats"]
```

The rest is just mapping and hashing:

```
Hash[names.map{|name| [name, doc.search("#{name} > #{name.sub /s$/, ''}").map(&:text)]}]
#=> {"cats"=>["John", "Peter"]}
```

Comment: nice! but can I get each element' content as a hash as well? i.e., how to turn `<cats><cat><name>John</name><age>10</age></cat></cats>` into `{'cats'=>[{'name'=>'John','age'=>10}]}`

Comment: I'll give you a hint, you would change the `(&:text)` to `{|x| Hash[x.search(' > *').map(something else)]}`